# How do I count the number of rows that contain a value earlier than another row in R?

Tags: r

I've imported data from a CSV into RStudio using read.table
The data is of the type "list" and looks like this:

| Client | Goal1 | Goal2 | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 0 | 1 | 9:00 |
| 123 | 1 | 0 | 9:15 |
| 234 | 1 | 0 | 9:12 |
| 234 | 0 | 1 | 9:30 |

I need to calculate the number of Clients that reached both Goal1 and Goal2, but Goal2 has to be reached after the Client reached Goal1.
So, in this example, Client 123 reached Goal2 before Goal1 and doesn't count. Client 234 reached Goal2 after Goal1 and does count.

I made a summary like this

```
scores %>% 
  summarise(count_all = n_distinct(Client), 
            count_goal_1 = uniqueN(Client[Goal1 > 0]), 
            count_goal_2 = uniqueN(Client[Goal2 > 0]), 
            count_overlap = uniqueN(ClientID[Goal1 > 0 & Goal2 > 0]),
            percentage_overlap = (count_overlap / count_goal_1)*100
  )
```

but I don't know how to make this conditional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can filter with the desired logic on data grouped by Client, then `summarise` with `n_distinct()`. It is important to change the Time column to hour:minute time format, we can do that with `lubridate::hm()`

```
library(dplyr)

d %>%
        mutate(Time = lubridate::hm(Time)) %>%
        group_by(Client) %>%
        filter(any(Goal2==1 & Time > Time[Goal1==1])) %>%
        ungroup() %>%
        summarise(n = n_distinct(Client))

# A tibble: 1 × 1
      n
  <int>
1     1
```

Comment: This seems simple enough :-)

One question: a Client can reach a goal multiple times.
Can I simply alter the filter like this?

```filter(any(Goal2==1 & min(Time) > min(Time[Goal1==1]))) %>%```

Comment: If a client meets the criteria multiple times, should they be counted as one or multiple cases? If it is one, the current code suffices, because 'any()' always evalueates to a single logical value for the every group.

Comment: Hi GuedesBF, the client should only be counted once as long as long as goal1 is reached at least once before goal2 is reached. So the answer should work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few key things here:

1. `pivot_longer` to get the different `Goal`s into a single column.
2. convert `Time` into an actual time format so you can calculate which was earlier.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <-
  read.table(header = T,
             text = "Client Goal1   Goal2   Time
                      123   0   1   9:00
                      123   1   0   9:15
                      234   1   0   9:12
                      234   0   1   9:30")

d %>%
  pivot_longer(
    starts_with("Goal"),
    names_to = "Goal",
    values_to = "is_goal",
    names_prefix = "Goal"
  ) %>%
  mutate(n_clients = length(unique(Client))) %>% # to keep for later as denominator of percentage
  mutate(Goal = as.integer(Goal)) %>% # turn to numeric so you can assess who got both
  filter(is_goal > 0) %>% # remove empty entries
  mutate(Time = hm(Time)) %>% # convert to time to calculate what was first
  group_by(Client) %>% # operate per-client
  filter(sum(Goal) == 3) %>%  # remove clients who didn't achieve both goals
  mutate(in_order = Time[Goal == 1] < Time[Goal == 2]) %>% # score whether goal 2 was after 1
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(in_order) %>% # remove clients who were not in order
  distinct(Client, n_clients) %>%
  summarise(percentage = 100 * nrow(.) / n_clients) # summarize as percentage
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   percentage
#>        <dbl>
#> 1         50
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I oversimplified the example. Clients can reach a goal multiple times so I'm going to have to tweak the filter. Anyone why reached the first goal 3 times and does not reach the second goal is still in the set, while someone who reaches both goals, but multiple times is filtered out.